# How to kill enemies with special immunities?

Tags: epic-defense-the-elements

I really enjoy this game but I simply can not kill some creatures. The skinny purple birds in wave 26th on the level called *"the Barrens"* seem to resist everything I throw at them, even though I had every kind of tower. Even the last wave was easier to deal with. I finished the level by buying more lives.

The same happens on the next level, *"Battle Plain"*, wave 24, the dragons with red backs and white bellies are indestructible.

Do you know of any special tower combinations that kill them easily?

Comment: Could someone create the tag "Epic Defense - the Elements" for me?

Answer (score -1):

Tried adding more or upgrade chain lightning towers, pair it with the one that freezes it (3 blue gems)

Comment: they seem to be lightning resistant